# EXCEL VBA Currency format in TextBox1

Tags: excel, vba, format, currency

I want to format the value in `TextBox1` with the following:

1. Ringgit Malaysia currency as in (RM) without the bracket
2. make it 2 decimal place e.g. RM 10.00
3. make the format appear in `TextBox1` even when user is not entering any value e.g. RM 0.00
4. allow user to enter integer only and also e.g. when user type 1234 in `TextBox1`, `TextBox1` value will change from RM 0.00 to RM 12.34 User don't have to hit the '`.`', the integer will just move front e.g. RM 0.01 -> RM 0.12 -> RM 1.23 -> RM 12.34 as user press 1234 in the `TextBox1`.

If any misunderstanding elsewhere within my questions, please let me know and I will correct it. Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First:** Your number format is easy enough. Open the Number format dialog box and create a custom format using this string:

"RM"#,#0.00

**Second:** To show empty cells as a zero, you have two options.

1. If the cells is a result of an equation or data somewhere else, you can use
   a formula; e.g., =if(A1="",0,A1) This will take the value of A1
   unless it is empty, in which case it would be 0.
2. You may also set the worksheet to display all zero values under
   options in the file tab.

**Third (and finally):** As far as the automatic placement of decimals, this is not uncommon. Simply follow the steps in this tutorial:

[How to insert decimal points automatically in Excel](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-insert-decimal-points-automatically-in-exce.html)

I hope this helps, good luck!

EDIT:

At first glance I thought you needed help with cell formatting, but you need help with a textbox control within a VBA Userform and/or a the worksheet itself. The tool that you need to accomplish this task is an Input Mask. However, from what I understand, there is currently no built-in support for this in a VBA userform. You can build code to do this when the user changes or exits the box.

I would recommend code when they exit that will first validate the input to confirm it is numeric, then change the value to match the desired format. Here is an example:

```
Private Sub myTextbox_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)

Dim myVal As String

myVal = Trim(myTextbox.Value)

If myVal = "" Then Exit Sub 'Ignore this subroutine if the box is empty.

If IsNumeric(myVal) = False Then 'If the input is not a number, ask for correct input.
    MsgBox "Please enter a number value."
    myTextbox.SetFocus
    Exit Sub
ElseIf InStr(1, myVal, ".", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then     'If the input includes decimal, use it.
    myTextbox.Value = "RM " & Format(myVal, "#,##0.00")
ElseIf InStr(1, myVal, ".", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then     'If the input doesn't include decimal, enter one and divide by 100.
    myTextbox.Value = "RM " & (Format(myVal, "#,##0.00") / 100)
End If


End Sub
```

And if you want to get really fancy, you can first search the input for "RM". This would ensure that an "invalid input" message box wouldn't pop up if the user entered a value such as "RM 123.45". Unfortunately I don't have time to write that code out for you at the moment.

Comment: I want to format directly in the TextBox not inside the cell. Sorry if that confuse you.

Comment: I wonder if it is possible. Thanks for your effort @Lopsided Much appreciated!